# KDE Plasma task manager does not show some apps during loading

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, kde, task-management

I have [kubuntu](/questions/tagged/kubuntu)[20.04](/questions/tagged/20.04) the task manager does not show the loading status with some applications when starting up them such as `code`. Sometimes I realize that the computer is not responding but I found two instances are opened because I did not informed about its loading. However, after the application loading completed it shows its icon.

Some other applications such as `FireFox` it displays the loading status just after double clicking on its icon for while and then it disappear until it is completely loaded.

Is there any solution or work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered an issue with IntelliJ where the icon specified in the .desktop file was in .svg format. However, by changing it to .png format, the problem was successfully resolved.

Here is an example image:

[image]